# C# Windows Forms Spotify API User Authorization

Tags: c#, winforms, spotify

I'm trying to authorize a spotify user in my `windows forms` application. I am able to make a `GET` call to the web `API`, and I get a response back that is `HTML`. When loaded into the browser, this `HTML` is a login page, but my question is two parts.

1) What would be the best way to display this login page. Obviously if I could launch the browser and have it return the authorization code somehow, that would be best, which brings me to my second question.

2) How would I get the authorization code from the browser when I launch the login screen? I can't see a way that my forms application would be able to receive any information after the login screen is launched. Sorry if this seems obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the URL I was using was not meant to be requested from, but to have the user navigate to in their browser. I basically just put the link in my application as a button and it would launch in chrome. Once the user logs in, I used http://httpbin.org/get to display the authentication code and just copied the code into my app as a temporary fix. Obviously this is not ready for release, and I am still working out how to get the code from the redirect url to my application, but it's a step in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

1) You can display a web browser inside your form to do the login part.
2) Browsers like Chrome can't return values. You could look at the data sent / received from your browser and search for an authentication token or something like that